# admin_signin Activity cannot be cast to android.app.activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tecno.applock.admin_signin cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

This is the manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.tecno.applock"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1.0" > <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="8"
           android:targetSdkVersion="19" />    
          <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 

          >
       <activity
        android:name="com.tecno.applock.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
       android:name="admin_signin"></activity>
       <activity
       android:name="create_guest"></activity>
       <activity
        android:name="delete"></activity>
        <activity
         android:name="edit"></activity>
         <activity
         android:name="Welcom_admin"></activity>
   </application> </manifest>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`android:name="com.tecno.applock.activity_name"` for each `Activity` (full path within your package)

Answer (score 1):

Do all of your activities extend the Activity class? You only need to list the classes that extend it in your manifest.

Also, are the package paths correct for all of these activities?

Comment: Based on the exception you posted, check if your admin_signin class extends Activity.